# How to restrict child data insertion in an integration, if Parent insertion fails?

Tags: integration, wsdl, inboundservices

I have the below Inbound Integration class, from which a WSDL is generated and shared with the middleware, to insert data in ServiceMax (also known as SMax - an appexchange product), from SAP:-

```
/*
Class Name: ESMX_SAP_Case_InboundIntegration
Purpose/Overview: Used by ESB middlewhere to Send Case details to SMAX.
Developer: Abhijeet Mitra
Created Date: 24-MAY-2018
Date Modified: Developer Name: Section/Page Block Modified/Added: Purpose/Overview of Change
************** *************** ********************************** **************************

*/
global class ESMX_SAP_Case_InboundIntegration{
    global class Status {                                           // inner class to provide a response structure for the service
        public Status() {
            statusCode = '-1';
            errorMsg = null;            
        }
        webservice String statusCode;                               // error code; to be defined by application logic
        webservice String errorMsg;                                 // a string description of the error
        webservice List<Case_info> caseList;                        // a List of Case records
        webservice List<CL_info> clList;                            // a List of Case Line records


    }

    public ESMX_SAP_Case_InboundIntegration(){}   

    global class Case_Info {                                        // Class for defining the input variables for WebService
        WebService String LocName;                                  // Location Name
        WebService String ShipToAddress;                            // SAP# for Ship To Address
        WebService String BillToAddress;                            // DUNS# of SoldTo Party
        WebService String BillToNumber;                             // SAP# of BillTo
        WebService String SoldToParty;                              // SAP# for SoldTo Party
        WebService String RecordTypeId;                             // RecordType of Location       
        WebService String GeRigId;                                  // Rig Id of Location
        WebService String Street;                                   // Street of Location
        WebService String City;                                     // City of Location
        WebService String State;                                    // Region of Location
        WebService String Country;                                  // Country of Location
        WebService String Zip;                                      // Postal Code of Location
        WebService String SitePhone;                                // SitePhone of Location
        WebService String SiteFax;                                  // SiteFax of Location
        WebService String ErrorMsg;                                 // Error Message of Location        
    }

    global class IP_Info {                                    // Class for defining the input variables for WebService
        WebService String LocName;                                  // Location Name
        WebService String ShipToAddress;                            // SAP# for Ship To Address
        WebService String BillToAddress;                            // DUNS# for Bill To Address
        WebService String BillToNumber;                             // SAP# of BillTo
        WebService String SoldToParty;                              // SAP# for SoldTo Party
        WebService String PartNumber;                               // PartNumber
        WebService String Serial;                                   // Serial/Lot Number
        WebService Decimal EquipmentNumber;                         // Equipment Number
        WebService String InstalledProductId;                       // Installed Product Id
        WebService String IPUniqueId;                               // Installed Product Unique Id      
        WebService String GeRigId;                                  // GE Rig Id of Location        
        WebService String IPStatus;                                 // Status of Installed Product
        WebService String ErrorMsg;                                 // Error Message of InstalledProduct
    } 


//webService for Location Insertion
   webservice static Status InsertLocation(List<Location_Info> LocationList, String BusinessUnit) {
        Status locStatus = new Status();
        String logDescription;
        Set<String> strLoc = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strRig = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strShipToAddress = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strBillToAddress = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strSoldToParty = new Set<String>{};
        String strBusinessUnit=BusinessUnit;


        List<SVMXC__Site__c> lstLocName= new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();
        List<SVMXC__Site__c> lstShipTo=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();
        List<SVMXC__Site__c> lstSoldTo=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();
        List<Account> lstBillTo=new List<Account>();

        List<SVMXC__Site__c> lstLoc=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();
        List<SVMXC__Site__c> updateList=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();


        List<Location_Info> locationsToInsert = new List<Location_Info>();
        List<Location_Info> locationsToNotify = new List<Location_Info>(); 
        List<Location_Info> finalList = new List<Location_Info>(); 
        try{ 

            for(Location_Info locinfo : LocationList) 
             {  
                //Separating Records when expected parameters of Location not provided.            
                if(locinfo.LocName!='' && locinfo.ShipToAddress!='' && locinfo.BillToAddress!='' && locinfo.RecordTypeId!='' && strBusinessUnit!='' && locinfo.SoldToParty!='' && locinfo.BillToNumber!='')
                {
                    strRig.add(locinfo.GeRigId);
                    strLoc.add(locinfo.LocName);
                    strBillToAddress.add(locinfo.BillToAddress); 
                    strShipToAddress.add(locinfo.ShipToAddress);

                   locationsToInsert.add(locinfo);
                }
                else{                        
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = 'Missing Mandatory Data - ';
                    if(locinfo.LocName==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'Location Name;';
                    }
                    if(locinfo.ShipToAddress==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'ShipToNumber;';
                    }
                    if(locinfo.BillToAddress==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'Bill To DUNS#;';
                    }
                    if(locinfo.RecordTypeId==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'RecordType;';
                    }
                    if(strBusinessUnit==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'BusinessUnit;';
                    }
                    if(locinfo.SoldToParty==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'SoldToParty;';
                    }
                    if(locinfo.BillToNumber==''){
                    locinfo.ErrorMsg = locinfo.ErrorMsg +'BillToNumber;';
                    }

                    locationsToNotify.add(locinfo);           
                }
             }          

            if(locationsToInsert.size()>0)
            { 
                GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility utility = new GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility();

                //Pulling Account details using DUNS#                
                lstBillTo = utility.accountDetails(strBillToAddress);

                //Verifying Location Names in ServiceMax
                lstLocName = utility.locDetails(strRig,'LocRigId',strShipToAddress);                

                    for(Location_Info loc: locationsToInsert)
                    {                        
                        integer nameCount=0;
                        integer billToCount=0;

                        SVMXC__Site__c location = new SVMXC__Site__c();

                        if(loc.RecordTypeId == 'Well')
                        {                            
                            location.RecordTypeId = utility.getRecTypeId('location',GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility.WELL_LOCATION_RECORD_TYPE);
                            location.Name = loc.LocName;
                            location.GE_OG_Sold_to_Party__c=loc.SoldToParty;
                            location.GE_OG_AL_Ship_to_Account_Number__c=loc.ShipToAddress;
                            location.GE_AL_Well__c=true;
                            location.GE_OG_AL_Bill_to_Account_Number__c=loc.BillToNumber;
                            location.SVMXC__Street__c=loc.Street;
                            location.SVMXC__City__c=loc.City;
                            location.SVMXC__Zip__c=loc.Zip;
                            location.SVMXC__Site_Phone__c=loc.SitePhone;
                            location.SVMXC__Site_Fax__c=loc.SiteFax;
                            location.SVMXC__State__c=loc.State;
                            location.SVMXC__Country__c=loc.country;                         

                            for(Account billTo:lstBillTo){
                                if(billTo.GE_HQ_DUNS_Number__c==loc.BillToAddress)
                                {
                                    location.SVMXC__Account__c = billTo.id;
                                    billToCount=1;
                                }
                            }
                            if(billToCount==0){
                                loc.ErrorMsg = 'Invalid Bill To Address;';
                                locationsToNotify.add(loc);
                            }
                            if(strBusinessUnit!='AL' && billToCount==1){
                                loc.ErrorMsg = loc.ErrorMsg + 'Invalid Business Unit;';
                                locationsToNotify.add(loc);
                            }

                            if(billToCount==1 && strBusinessUnit=='AL')
                            {    if(lstLocName.size()>0)
                                {
                                    for(SVMXC__Site__c locs:lstLocName){                            
                                    if(locs.GE_Rig_ID__c==loc.GeRigId) 
                                        location.id=locs.id;
                                    }                       
                                } 

                                lstLoc.add(location);                           
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                        loc.ErrorMsg = 'Invalid RecordType';
                        locationsToNotify.add(loc);
                        }                           
                    }   

                    //Upserting Locations
                        if(lstLoc.size()>0){
                             upsert lstLoc;

                             System.debug('Locations Upserted Successfully to SMax.');
                             locStatus.statusCode='0';

                             List<SVMXC__Site__c> newLocation = utility.locDetails(strLoc,'Name',strShipToAddress);
                             List<Location_Info> temp = new List<Location_Info>();

                             for(SVMXC__Site__c ltn: newLocation){
                                 Location_Info loct = new Location_Info();
                                 loct.LocName=ltn.Name;
                                 loct.GeRigId=ltn.GE_Rig_ID__c;                                
                                 temp.add(loct);
                             }
                             locStatus.locList=temp;
                             finalList=temp;
                        }
            }          

            if(locationsToNotify.size()>0){

                // Email Notification logic
                 locStatus.statusCode='-1';
                 locStatus.errorMsg = 'Error in Insertion/Updation of Location(s)';
                 for(Location_Info ltn: locationsToNotify){
                     Location_Info locat = new Location_Info();
                     locat.LocName=ltn.LocName; 
                     locat.errorMsg=ltn.errorMsg;
                    finalList.add(locat);                    
                 }
                 locStatus.locList=finalList;
            }
            if(lstLoc.size()>0 && locationsToNotify.size()>0){
                locStatus.statusCode='-2';              
            }  

          return locStatus;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error in Insertion : '+ex +'---'+ ex.getLineNumber());
            locStatus.statusCode='-3'; 
            locStatus.errorMsg = 'Error in Insertion/Updation of Location(s) in ServiceMax'; 
            logDescription='GE_OG_SAP_InboundIntegration:' +ex.getLineNumber()+'---'+ex.getMessage()+'---'+ex.getStackTraceString()+'---'+ex.getTypeName();
            System.debug('Log Description: '+logDescription);
            List<Location_Info> locationsToError = new List<Location_Info>();
            for(SVMXC__Site__c ssc:lstLoc )
            {
                Location_Info errLoc = new Location_Info();
                errLoc.LocName=ssc.name;
                errLoc.BillToNumber=ssc.GE_OG_AL_Bill_to_Account_Number__c;
                errLoc.ShipToAddress=ssc.GE_OG_AL_Ship_to_Account_Number__c;
                errLoc.ErrorMsg=logDescription;

                locationsToError.add(errLoc);   
            }

            GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility.notifyInboundLocation(locationsToError,logDescription);         
            return locStatus;
        }        
   }




//webService for Installed Product Insertion    
  webservice static Status InsertInstalledProduct(List<IP_Info> InstalledProductList, String BusinessUnit) {
        Status ipStatus = new Status();
        String logDescription;
        Set<String> strBillToAddress = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strPartNumber = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strSerial = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strInstalledProductId = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strGeRigId = new Set<String>{};
        Set<String> strShipToAddress = new Set<String>{};
        String strBusinessUnit=BusinessUnit;

        List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> ipList= new List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>();
        List<Account> lstShipTo=new List<Account>();
        List<Account> lstBillTo=new List<Account>();
        List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> lstInstalledProduct= new List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c>();
        List<SVMXC__Site__c> lstRigs=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();



        List<IP_Info> IPsToInsert = new List<IP_Info>();
        List<IP_Info> IPsToNotify = new List<IP_Info>();
        List<IP_Info> finalList = new List<IP_Info>();
        try{ 

                for(IP_Info ipinfo : InstalledProductList) 
                 {  
                    //Separating Records when expected parameters of Location not provided.            
                    if(ipinfo.GeRigId!='' && ipinfo.ShipToAddress!='' && ipinfo.BillToAddress!='' && ipinfo.PartNumber!='' && ipinfo.Serial!='' && ipinfo.InstalledProductId!='' && ipinfo.SoldToParty!='' && strBusinessUnit!='')
                    {  
                       strBillToAddress.add(ipinfo.BillToAddress);
                       strSerial.add(ipinfo.Serial);
                       strGeRigId.add(ipinfo.GeRigId);
                       strShipToAddress.add(ipinfo.ShipToAddress);

                       IPsToInsert.add(ipinfo);
                    }
                    else{ 
                        ipinfo.ErrorMsg='Missing Mandatory Data - ';
                        if(ipinfo.GeRigId=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'GeRigId;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.ShipToAddress=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'ShipToNumber;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.BillToAddress=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'Bill To DUNS#;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.PartNumber=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'PartNumber;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.Serial=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'Serial#;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.InstalledProductId=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'InstalledProductId;';
                        }
                        if(ipinfo.SoldToParty=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'SoldToParty;';
                        }
                        if(strBusinessUnit=='')
                        { 
                            ipinfo.ErrorMsg = ipinfo.ErrorMsg + 'BusinessUnit;';
                        }

                        IPsToNotify.add(ipinfo);                    
                    }
                 }           

                if(IPsToInsert.size()>0)
                { 
                    GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility utility = new GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility();
                    //Pulling Account details using DUNS#                   
                    lstBillTo = utility.accountDetails(strBillToAddress);

                    //Pulling Location details using GE Rig Id
                    lstRigs = utility.locDetails(strGeRigId,'RigId',strShipToAddress); 

                    //Verifying Serial/Lot Numbers n ServiceMax
                    ipList = utility.ipDetails(strSerial,strBusinessUnit);  

                    for(IP_Info ip: IPsToInsert)
                    {
                        integer locCount=0;
                        integer billToCount=0;


                        SVMXC__Installed_Product__c installedProd   = new SVMXC__Installed_Product__c();
                        if(strBusinessUnit=='AL')
                        {
                            installedProd.RecordTypeId = utility.getRecTypeId('InstalledProduct',GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility.AL_InstalledProduct_RECORD_TYPE);
                            installedProd.GE_OG_Sold_to_Party__c = ip.SoldToParty;
                            installedProd.SVMXC__Status__c = ip.IPStatus;
                            installedProd.GE_AL_Equipment_Number__c = ip.EquipmentNumber;
                            installedProd.GE_OG_AL_Ship_to_Account_Number__c = ip.ShipToAddress;
                            installedProd.Name = ip.InstalledProductId;
                            installedProd.SVMXC__Serial_Lot_Number__c=ip.Serial;
                            installedProd.GE_OG_DS_Part_Number__c=ip.PartNumber;
                            installedProd.GE_OG_AL_Bill_to_Account_Number__c=ip.BillToNumber;

                            for(SVMXC__Site__c rig:lstRigs){
                                if(rig.GE_Rig_ID__c==ip.GeRigId){
                                    installedProd.SVMXC__Site__c=rig.Id;
                                    locCount = 1;                              
                                    }                           
                                }                             
                            if(locCount!=1) {
                                ip.errorMsg='Invalid Location GE RIG Id';
                                IPsToNotify.add(ip);
                            }                       

                            if(locCount == 1)
                            {
                                for(Account billTo:lstBillTo){
                                    if(billTo.GE_HQ_DUNS_Number__c==ip.BillToAddress)
                                    {
                                        installedProd.SVMXC__Company__c = billTo.id;
                                        billToCount = 1; 
                                    }                
                                }
                            } 
                            if(billToCount != 1 && locCount==1){
                                ip.errorMsg='Invalid Location Bill To DUNS#';
                                IPsToNotify.add(ip);
                            }


                            if(billToCount==1 && locCount==1){                             
                                if(ipList.size()>0){
                                    for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c iplst:ipList){                          
                                        if(iplst.SVMXC__Serial_Lot_Number__c==ip.Serial && iplst.GE_OG_DS_Part_Number__c==ip.PartNumber)
                                            installedProd.id=iplst.id; 
                                    }                       
                                }
                                lstInstalledProduct.add(installedProd);  
                            }

                        }
                        else{
                                ip.ErrorMsg = 'Invalid RecordType';
                                IPsToNotify.add(ip);
                            }
                    }
                    //Insert Installed Product 
                        if(lstInstalledProduct.size()>0){
                        System.debug('List to Insert'+ lstInstalledProduct);
                         upsert lstInstalledProduct;

                         System.debug('Installed Product upserted Successfully to SMax.');
                         ipStatus.statusCode='0';

                         List<SVMXC__Installed_Product__c> newIp = utility.ipDetails(strSerial,strBusinessUnit);
                             List<IP_Info> temp = new List<IP_Info>();

                             for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c iprd: newIp){
                                for(IP_Info ipinf: IPsToInsert){
                                    if(iprd.SVMXC__Serial_Lot_Number__c==ipinf.Serial && iprd.GE_OG_DS_Part_Number__c==ipinf.PartNumber){
                                     IP_Info iprod = new IP_Info();
                                     iprod.InstalledProductId = iprd.Name;
                                     iprod.IPUniqueId = iprd.GE_HQ_SFDC_LEGACY_ID__c; 
                                     iprod.EquipmentNumber = iprd.GE_AL_Equipment_Number__c;                               
                                     temp.add(iprod);
                                 }
                                }
                             }
                             ipStatus.ipList=temp;
                             finalList=temp;
                        }

                }

                if(IPsToNotify.size()>0){                

                 ipStatus.statusCode='-1';
                 ipStatus.errorMsg = 'Error while Insertion/updation of InstalledProduct(s)';

                 for(IP_Info instPrd: IPsToNotify){
                     IP_Info iproduct = new IP_Info();
                     iproduct.InstalledProductId=instPrd.InstalledProductId;
                     iproduct.EquipmentNumber =instPrd.EquipmentNumber ;                     
                     iproduct.ErrorMsg=instPrd.ErrorMsg;
                     finalList.add(iproduct);
                    }
                    ipStatus.ipList=finalList;
                }
                if(IPsToNotify.size()>0 && lstInstalledProduct.size()>0){
                     ipStatus.statusCode='-2';
                 } 
            return ipStatus;         

            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Error in Insertion : '+ex);
            ipStatus.statusCode='-3'; 
            ipStatus.errorMsg = 'Error while Insertion/updation of Install Product(s) in ServiceMax'; 
            logDescription='GE_OG_SAP_InboundIntegration:' +ex.getLineNumber()+'---'+ex.getMessage()+'---'+ex.getStackTraceString()+'---'+ex.getTypeName();
            System.debug('Log Description: '+logDescription);
            List<IP_Info> tempList = new List<IP_Info>();
            for(SVMXC__Installed_Product__c instPrds: lstInstalledProduct){
                     IP_Info iproduct = new IP_Info();
                     iproduct.InstalledProductId = instPrds.Name;
                     iproduct.GeRigId= instPrds.SVMXC__Site__c;
                     iproduct.Serial= instPrds.SVMXC__Serial_Lot_Number__c;
                     iproduct.PartNumber= instPrds.GE_OG_DS_Part_Number__c;
                     iproduct.ErrorMsg=logDescription;
                     tempList.add(iproduct);
                    }
            GE_OG_SAP_IntegrationUtility.notifyInboundIP(tempList,logDescription);
            return ipStatus;
        } 
  }

}
```

Currently the **Location** object data and the **Installed Product** object data are being inserted by the middleware in one request, and the code is also inserting them, with some validations.
The new ask is, that once the **Location** record is successfully inserted and the Salesforce Id is generated, then only the **Installed Product** should be inserted, along with the **Location** record Id, as it's Parent field data. This can easily be done by the middleware, but they don't want to make 2 calls in one transaction to minimize the timeout errors. So kindly advice me what changes do I need to make in the code, to achieve the above said scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Abhijeet, if I'm understanding correctly what you want to do is insert the child records only for the parent records that were successfully inserted, and ignore any child records that are related to parent records that were not inserted successfully.

First of all, if you are going to send both parent and child records in just one API call:

1. You will need to create an External Id field in the parent object
   (Location).
2. The middle ware will need to provide that Id to be able to identify the parent record (Location).
3. The middle ware will need to provide the External Id of the parent record for each child record (Installed Location) to be able to recreate the relationship.

So when the middle ware connects to Salesforce it will provide the following lists of records:

- ParentRecordList(ExternalId__c: MiddlewareParentId, ...)
- ChildrenRecordList(ParentID__c: MiddlewareParentId, ...)

Now you can use something similar to this:

```
// Attempt to insert all the parent records
Database.SaveResult[] parentResult = Database.insert(parents, false);
Set<String> externalIdOfParentsSuccessfulyInserted = new Set<String>();

// Identify which parent records were successfully inserted
for(Integer i = 0; i < parentResult.size(); i++) {
  if (parentResult[i].isSuccess()) {
    externalIdOfParentsSuccessfulyInserted.add(parents.get(i).ExternalID__c);
  }
}

List<Child__c> chilrenToBeInserted = new List<Children__c>();
for (Child__c child : children) {
  // Only try to create the children for the parent records that were successfully created
  if (externalIdOfParentsSuccessfulyInserted.contains(child.ParentLocationID__c)) {
    // Recreate the relationship between child and parent
    Parent__c parent = new Parent__c(ExternalID__c = child.ParentLocationID__c);
    child.ParentLocationID__r = parent;
    childrenToBeInserted.add(child);
  }
}
Database.insert(childrenToBeInserted);
```

This doesn't take into consideration that the child records may fail, in which case you will also need to create a save point and rollback the changes as indicated by @sfdcfox.

Reference: [Relating Records by Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm)

Comment: Hi @Marco, thanks for the reply. One clarification needed. As the middleware is inserting both the data in one single push, where should I be writing the above snippet (provided by you) in the WSDL class? should it be in the webservice method of Parent insertion?

Comment: Hi @Abhijeet, yes, you would have this logic on the web service method, the middleware should provide both the parent and child records data and this single method would take care of handling the insertion of both sets of records. You could of course split this in different private methods to organize the logic, but the middleware would access it through a single web service call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to sort through all your code for a total rewrite, but the safest way to do this is by way of save points.

The pseudo-code for that would look like this:

```
while(true) {
    Database.SavePoint sp = Database.setSavePoint();
    Database.SaveResult[] parentSaves = Database.insert(parents, false);
    for(Integer i = parentSaves.size() - 1; i != -1; i--) {
        if(!parentSaves[i].isSuccess()) {
            parents.remove(i); // Remove failed record
            // Depending on API design, log these as errors
        }
    }
    if(parentSaves.size() != parents.size()) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        continue; // At least one failure, try again
    }
    children = buildChildren(parents);
    Database.SaveResult[] childSaves = Database.insert(children, false);
    for(Integer i = children.size()-1; i != -1; i--) {
        if(!childSaves[i].isSuccess()) {
            // Somehow calculate which parent failed...
            Integer parentIndex = findParentForChild(parents, children[i]);
            parents.remove(parentIndex); // Remove failed record
            // Depending on API design, log these as errors
        }
    }
    if(childSaves.size() != children.size()) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        continue; // At least one failure, try again
    }
    break; // No more failures occurred
}
```

As stated, this is not a full solution, but if you break this up in to additional methods, it should be quite manageable. If you can guarantee the children will always save, you might want to skip the second set of rollback logic for performance reasons, although I'd recommend doing it anyways, since someone could later add a rule that could cause your saves to fail.